# How redirect to other page using HTML or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-4

Im begginer in WebProgramming so maybe my questuion will seem naive to some of you.
I want to run a simple JavaScript function without any click to implement a redirection.

I try this:

```
@inherits System.Web.WebPages.WebPage
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
</head>
<body>
     <a href="/OauthCallBack/GmailOAuthCallback"></a>
</body>
</html>
```

But it dosen't work.

Any idea wat I am missing?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You haven't got any JavaScript in the code you've shared. (But if you want to do a redirect, then do it with an HTTP Location header, not with JavaScript).

Comment: Your title states "HTML or Javascript" but your question only only mentions javascript.  If you're happy with HTML, then [look at META redirection](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H76.html) `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='http://www.example.com/'" />`

Comment: Your probobly missing the _text_ for your <a> link (^_^)

Comment: You must write some text between anchor open tag<a> and close tag </a>,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Meta tag for client side redirection.

```
<META http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL=http://www.example.com">
```

Which will redirect the user to http://www.example.com after 5 seconds.

Comment: But I need to redirect to the file in the project no to the external site.

Comment: In your case, try this: content="5;URL=/OauthCallBack/GmailOAuthCallback"

Answer (score 5):

Simply use window.location="http://www.newlocation.com". See the example below:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function Redirect()
{
    window.location="http://www.newlocation.com";
}

document.write("You will be redirected to main page in 10 sec.");
setTimeout('Redirect()', 10000);
//-->
</script>
</head>
```

[More info here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_page_redirect.htm)

Answer (score 1):

`window.location` is a property of window object.

You can try function version too

`function myCustomHref() {
   window.open ('http://www.newlocation.com', '_self');
}`

[Here you can find more optional properties](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)

Comment: I shiver ever time I see a reference to [w3fools.com](http://www.w3fools.com/) (click link to see why they should be avoided)

Answer (score 1):

if you want to redirect from a webpage to another using javascript,then you can try the following script,

```
<script>
function newPage() {
    window.location.assign("http://www.w3schools.com")
}
</script>
```

For full details you can view the following website,

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp

Comment: I shiver ever time I see a reference to [w3fools.com](http://www.w3fools.com/) (click link to see why they should be avoided)